# PL/SQL insert sum value into dest table and update source table at the same time

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables TRANSACTION and PROCESS. I need to store the total transaction amount of each shop in the process table, AND once the transaction is processed, the processId in the TRANSACTION table should be updated.

Table: TRANSACTION

[image]

Table: PROCESS

[image]

However, currently I can only insert the values in to the PROCESS table:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO process
    (processId, shopId, totalTransactionAmount)
    SELECT my_seq.NEXTVAL, shop, total
    FROM
        (SELECT shopId shop, sum(transactionAmount) total
         FROM transaction
         GROUP BY shopId);
END;
```

But how can I update the transaction table with the processId once the transaction is processed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example using `forall` and `bulk collect`.

**Supporting database objects:**

```
create table transaction (
 transaction_id number
,shop_id varchar2(2)
,transaction_amount number
,process_id number
);

insert all
into transaction values(1, 's1', 10, null)
into transaction values(2, 's2',  8, null)
into transaction values(3, 's1',  5, null)
into transaction values(4, 's2', 15, null)
select 1 from dual;

create table process (
 process_id number
,shop_id varchar2(2)
,total_transaction_amount number
);

create sequence process_id_s start with 2016042900;
```

**Processing with PL/SQL:**

```
declare
  -- required supporting data structures
  type transaction_t is record(
   shop_id varchar2(2)
  ,total_amount number
  );
  type transaction_list_t is table of transaction_t;

  type process_t is record(
   process_id number
  ,shop_id varchar2(2)
  );
  type process_list_t is table of process_t;

  v_transactions transaction_list_t;
  v_processes process_list_t;
begin
  -- collect transaction data to PL/SQL data structure
  select shop_id, sum(transaction_amount)
  bulk collect into v_transactions
  from transaction
  where process_id is null
  group by shop_id
  ;

  -- insert transaction data to process-table and collect process and shop ids
  -- to PL/SQL data structure
  forall i in v_transactions.first .. v_transactions.last
    insert into process(process_id, shop_id, total_transaction_amount)
    values(process_id_s.nextval, v_transactions(i).shop_id, v_transactions(i).total_amount)
    returning process_id, shop_id bulk collect into v_processes
  ;

  -- update process id to transaction-table
  forall i in v_processes.first .. v_processes.last
    update transaction set
    process_id = v_processes(i).process_id
    where shop_id = v_processes(i).shop_id
  ;
end;
/
```

**Example run:**

```
SQL> @so55

Table created.

4 rows created.

TRANSACTION_ID SH TRANSACTION_AMOUNT PROCESS_ID
-------------- -- ------------------ ----------
             1 s1                 10
             2 s2                  8
             3 s1                  5
             4 s2                 15

Table created.

Sequence created.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

PROCESS_ID SH TOTAL_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
---------- -- ------------------------
2016042900 s2                       23
2016042901 s1                       15

TRANSACTION_ID SH TRANSACTION_AMOUNT PROCESS_ID
-------------- -- ------------------ ----------
             1 s1                 10 2016042901
             2 s2                  8 2016042900
             3 s1                  5 2016042901
             4 s2                 15 2016042900

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you call my_sql.nextval in your insert, you can reference it in the next insert for the same transaction by the CURRVAL pseudo column, which will have the current sequence value just generated.  So something like:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO process
(processId, shopId, totalTransactionAmount)
SELECT my_seq.NEXTVAL, shop, total
FROM
(SELECT shopId shop, sum(transactionAmount) total
 FROM transaction
 GROUP BY shopId);

**insert into transaction (..) values ( my_seq.currval, ....**
END;
```